# Be notified of an update to an app that is not installed

Tags: google-play-store, updates, notifications

Is there any way to receive an update/new version released notification from the Play Store for an app that is not installed in my phone? I'm using 4.3 on a Nexus 4.

Answer (score 5):

With [Changelog Droid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cypressworks.changelogviewer) being *currently* "out of order"<sup>1</sup>, let me mention an alternative:

**[App Watcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anod.appwatcher)** claims to do the very same:

> App Watcher notifies you about updates of applications from Play Store even the app is not installed currently on your device and provides quick access to the "What's new" section.

[image: App Watcher] [image: App Watcher]
<sup>*App Watcher* (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anod.appwatcher); click images for larger variants)</sup>

<sup>**1:**  (according to [a comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/51583/16575#comment-127769) from [winchendonsprings](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/18330/winchendonsprings)); by a response I've got from the dev, he's quite busy with other tasks at the moment, but did not abandon the app – he still plans to update it, but cannot give an estimate.</sup>